# Mixing constrained auto placeholder as non-trailing return type and explicit trailing return type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

**Can we mix constrained `auto` placeholder as non-trailing return type and trailing return type?**

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3YoEnzEbY)

```cpp
template<class T>
concept C = sizeof(T) > sizeof(char);

C auto g1(auto) -> int { return 1; }
C auto g2(auto) -> char { return '2'; }

int main() {
  return g1(0) + g2(0); 
}
```

- GCC & MSVC: ok, returns `1 + '2'`, even if `g2` returns a `char`
- Clang: error with `function with trailing return type must specify return type 'auto', not 'C auto'`

I was expecting that

```cpp
Concept auto foo(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b)
{ return a + b; }
```

is equivalent to

```cpp
auto foo(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b)
    requires Concept<decltype(a + b)>
{ return a + b; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can constrain the return type at all. The auto return type should be deduced, but then you constrain it. Constrain the inputs not the output and it'll be fine.

Comment: @simre I'm not sure either. But both `auto g3(auto) -> C auto {return 3;}` and `C auto g4(auto) {return 4;}` are accepted by GCC, Clang and MSVC.

Comment: I mean use `auto foo(Concept auto a, Concept auto b) -> someType {}` The first auto must be simply auto. Constrain the inputs, not the outputs.

Comment: @simre > *The first auto must be simply auto.*  Can you give any source about this?

Comment: I cannot find the section for that in the latest standard draft, but I'll look for that. For now I found this quickly, https://www.ibm.com/docs/de/zos/2.3.0?topic=declarators-trailing-return-type-c11 
It clearly says it MUST be auto (I know it is C++11): "When a trailing return type is used, the placeholder return type must be auto. For example, the statement auto *f()->char results in a compile-time error, because auto * is not allowed as the placeholder return type."

Comment: @simre I agree that is true before C++20. I'm not sure if the page you linked is up to date of C++20, although the page says that it is "updated" in 2021.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243965/discussion-between-vainman-and-simre).

Comment: The trailing return type is explicit, not deduced. No deduction = no concepts.

Comment: Yes, but in this case he is mixing up the auto return type with a placeholder, and a trailing return type.

Answer (score -1):

They are not equivalent. First of all, correctly:

```
auto foo(auto a, auto b) -> Concept decltype(a + b) // or Concept auto
{ return a + b; }
```

it defines a foo function, which returns the type `decltype(a + b)`, which is constrained by `Concept`. If it cannot, you get a compile time error.
The other:

```
auto foo(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b)
    requires Concept<decltype(a + b)>
{ return a + b; }
```

will return a type of `decltype(a + b)`, but this FUNCTION (not the retun type) is constrained to be valid only if `decltype(a + b)` fulfills the `Concept`, so if it doesn't you won't get any errors, since this function is cannot be used at all due to the requires clause.

For the 'Mixing' part of the question:
With `C auto g1(auto) -> int { return 1; }`, you say something like "g1 will return some deduced type (auto) which must fulfill the C concept, and then you say return `int`. It is kinda weird. So you tell the compiler to deduce the type, then you explicitly say what type to return. I think it makes no sense...

Also the standard [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#general-3) say that:

> "If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type ([dcl.fct]), that trailing-return-type specifies the declared return type of the function."

I don't find anything if the standard does not allow the `C auto` at the begining, but it explicitly defines that if you have a trailing-return type, the trailing-return type specifies the returned type, and not the placeholder auto.
So in GCC and MSVC it could be a bug, or they simply ignores that intentionally...

Comment: You don't need trailing return type at all here.

Comment: Yes I know, but with the trailing return type, this would be the equivalent. Even if it is kinda useless.

Comment: On the count of "uselessness", this isn't some whim. This syntax *must work* or lambda expressions could never use the feature.

Comment: Okay for a lambda. But this isn't a lambda. For this function it is just extra fancy stuff which only confuses everyone. I'm not sure if trailing return type on functions makes any sense with auto... I think it does not.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. Explicit concrete trailing return type is known in immediate context and is sfinae-friendly.

Comment: If you have `return a + b;`, then it's `auto return type` should be the same as `decltype(a + b)`, so in his example it is equivalent. But to be explicit, in the gobdolt example you yould use `return int(1);` and you are explicit.

Comment: See: https://godbolt.org/z/68Gs6KMjo

Comment: I think these are not the same. for foo1, you say "Compiler, figure out the return type for me, and cry if C does not fulfill." for foo2, you say "Compiler, figure out the return type for me, but only if C fulfills"
In one case you constrain the function itself, in the other case you constrain the return type. They are not the same.
You are doing the same as `auto foo2(auto a, auto b) -> C auto` with an extra constrain.

Comment: Yes, so they are not equivalent. That's exacly what I was saying in OP's code that use trailing return type and requires clause.

Comment: Ooooh okay. I see what you meen. Yes, you are right. I correct my answer.

Comment: Btw, I want to remind again, it isn't the requires clause but the concrete trailing return type in `foo2` that make the difference.

Comment: It is the requires clause, just add the requires to the other function too. See: https://godbolt.org/z/5oYWdW45e
But now you have the same constrain twice. First to check if the function is applicable, then to see if the returned type is good, which is the same requirement again, but 'after' the function call. If you don't constrain the function itself, then it'll try to deduce the type from `B() + B()` and USE!! that, which is impossible since you don't have that operator so it dies.

Comment: Okey, they both do. Because you introduce the expression `a + b` in requires cluase to immediate context. Removing the requires clause from `foo2` is ok too.

Comment: I'm playing with it and it is weird. I don't understand exactly what does `std::is_invocable` do exactly, but somehow it can understand from decltype that this is impossible, while for auto you need the resulted type somehow what you can't get and crash... And as I play, they works the same way, except the `std::is_invocable` trait...